# generating list of X.509 certificates and storing it in .bin file

Tags: openssl, certificate, google-apps, google-oauth, google-sso

i am trying to create a certificate for google marketplace app. i am trying to implement a interface http://code.google.com/p/step2/source/browse/code/java/trunk/common/src/main/java/com/google/step2/xmlsimplesign/TrustRootsProvider.java?r=383

my sourcecode is

```
public class AppEngineTrustsRootProvider implements TrustRootsProvider {

  private static final String CERT_FILE = "/cacerts.bin";

  private final Collection<X509Certificate> certs;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public AppEngineTrustsRootProvider() {

    try {
      ObjectInputStream in =
          new ObjectInputStream(AppEngineTrustsRootProvider.class.getResourceAsStream(CERT_FILE));
      certs = (Collection<X509Certificate>) in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public Collection<X509Certificate> getTrustRoots() {
    return certs;
  }
}
```

i read this article in which using openssl or keytool we can generate certificate in .cert file or in .der file but how to get list of certificates in .bin file . this is an example code snippet i am unable to figure it out how to get list of certificates in .bin file . please some one help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to get a group of certs together into a file.  This is often done through a KeyStore file, which can be of several formats.  Two popular formats are JKS and PKCS12.  You can use the Java `keytool` command or `openssl` to create the keystores.

Then programmatically, you can load the keystore file into a Java [KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) object.  From there you can use the `aliases()` method to retrieve all the aliases in the KeyStore.  Then you can go through each one with the `isCertificateEntry(alias)` method, and if true, add the resulting certificate from `getCertificate(alias)` into a Collection, that you will return at the end of the method.  There is some example code for loading a KeyStore from a file at the KeyStore link above.

Note that the `cacerts` file present in JRE installations is actually a JKS keystore.